# HTML/CSS/JS - How can I make the current page in my website be highlighted as a different color in the navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the website I am working on using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Currently, this website is in the home page. I want the "home" button to be highlighted in a different color to let the user identify what page they are in should they forget. Even in all of the other pages, I want that specific page to be highlighted in a different color. What should I do? Below is my Home Page HTML Code and CSS code and Java Script code (please note that for all the other HTML pages, each respective page has been called as active, the home page is not called active in all of the pages)

```
enter code here
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");

}
```

```css
body{
 background: #AED6F1!important;
 position:relative;
   margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h4{
 font-size: 25px !important;
 font-style:bold !important;
 color:yellow !important;
 font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif !important;

}

.a{
 font-size:30px !important;
 font-style: bold !important;
 color:  #008000 !important;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive !important;
}
.fixed-nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00a087;
}

footer {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:30px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:black;
   color:white;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: orange;
    border:5px;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover, ul.topnav li active a {background-color: red;}




/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .fixed-nav-bar{
    position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00a087;
}
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Team Zork</title>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/styles.css">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "js/script.js">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Lz4n-vyZFIU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/8GQ9KKFfq5Q/s100-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<nav class = "fixed-nav-bar">
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href = "index.html"><img src = "https://s32.postimg.org/euqw9qysl/Picture11.png" width="30px" height="30px"></a></li>
  <li class = "active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoLpDa5_Bb93xdLE0ooq1Vw"><img src = "https://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/media/image/YouTube-icon-full_color.png" width="40px" height="30px"></a></li>
  <li><a href = "https://twitter.com/TeamZorK"><img src ="https://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_blue.png" width="40px" height="30px"></a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>   
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id = "wrap">
<br><br><br><div class = "banner"><center><img src = "https://s31.postimg.org/dq98nwh7f/146833035336100_2.gif" width="50%" height ="75%"></center></div>
<br>
<marquee class = "a"> We are a professional gaming community that strives to provide you with the best gaming videos!</marquee>
<center><b><h4>CHECK OUT OUR LATEST VIDEO!</h4></b></center>
<center>
<div class = "vid"><iframe width="50%" height="405px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLYz-qmnLHRQH1hCfTHtjNNWQykjjpb9eA" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</center>


<footer>
<center><p>© 2016  Team Zork, Inc. </p></center>
</footer>




  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ajax-utils.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You shoudn't use `marquee`, it isn't standard HTML, and some web-browsers doesn't support it anymore.

Comment: What problem are you facing with setting a different color for an element with specific class?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `li active` instead of `li.active` in CSS

**Replace**

`ul.topnav li a:hover, ul.topnav li active a {background-color: red;}`

**With**

`ul.topnav li a:hover, ul.topnav li.active a {background-color: red;}`

Hope it helps

---

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");

}
```

```css
body{
 background: #AED6F1!important;
 position:relative;
   margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h4{
 font-size: 25px !important;
 font-style:bold !important;
 color:yellow !important;
 font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif !important;

}

.a{
 font-size:30px !important;
 font-style: bold !important;
 color:  #008000 !important;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive !important;
}
.fixed-nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00a087;
}

footer {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:30px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:black;
   color:white;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: orange;
    border:5px;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover, ul.topnav li.active a {background-color: red;}




/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .fixed-nav-bar{
    position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00a087;
}
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Team Zork</title>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/styles.css">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "js/script.js">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Lz4n-vyZFIU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/8GQ9KKFfq5Q/s100-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<nav class = "fixed-nav-bar">
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href = "index.html"><img src = "https://s32.postimg.org/euqw9qysl/Picture11.png" width="30px" height="30px"></a></li>
  <li class = "active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoLpDa5_Bb93xdLE0ooq1Vw"><img src = "https://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/media/image/YouTube-icon-full_color.png" width="40px" height="30px"></a></li>
  <li><a href = "https://twitter.com/TeamZorK"><img src ="https://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_blue.png" width="40px" height="30px"></a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>   
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id = "wrap">
<br><br><br><div class = "banner"><center><img src = "https://s31.postimg.org/dq98nwh7f/146833035336100_2.gif" width="50%" height ="75%"></center></div>
<br>
<marquee class = "a"> We are a professional gaming community that strives to provide you with the best gaming videos!</marquee>
<center><b><h4>CHECK OUT OUR LATEST VIDEO!</h4></b></center>
<center>
<div class = "vid"><iframe width="50%" height="405px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLYz-qmnLHRQH1hCfTHtjNNWQykjjpb9eA" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</center>


<footer>
<center><p>© 2016  Team Zork, Inc. </p></center>
</footer>




  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ajax-utils.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline style to customize the color of Home. You can also set the color dynamically using javascript.

```
<li class = "active"><a href="index.html" style="color:rgb(12,12,12);">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href = "index.html"><img src = "https://s32.postimg.org/euqw9qysl/Picture11.png" width="30px" height="30px"></a></li>
  <li class = "active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>


<li><a href = "index.html"><img src = "https://s32.postimg.org/euqw9qysl/Picture11.png" width="30px" height="30px"></a></li>
  <li ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class = "active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

you Just add this class="active" in all your pages for aboutpage apply page and soon..

Answer (score 0):

add `.active` class to link where you want different color

```
<li class="active" ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

it will be for home page

if you want diffrent color then add new class to your css or edit the current

```
.topnav>li.active>a, .topnav>li.active>a:focus, .topnav>li.active>a:hover{
 //change background color on hover focus
}
```

change only color of text

```
.topnav>li.active>a{
color:whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using static html for your website
then at each page you can declare 'active' class corresponding to its menu and slyle colors for this 'active' class

Exemple 'index.html'

```
 <li class = "active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
 <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

and about.html

```
<li ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class = "active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

and apply.html

```
<li ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li class = "active"><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

and blog.html

```
<li ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li ><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
<li class = "active"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

and contact.html

```
<li ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li ><a href="apply.html">Apply</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
<li  class = "active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

and style

```
ul.topnav li a:hover, ul.topnav li.active a {background-color: red;}
```